# get text area validated

Tags: javascript, validation, textarea

f

this is an external javascript , but he name and email works correctly but it skips over the message box and goes to info submitted even if the text area is empty. I've tried multiple ways and I tried to different functions and calling both and it didn't work correctly i do want to keep the if statements because I honestly don't know another way that doesn't mess with my other code..

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem — http://jsbin.com/kaseje/1/edit?html,output — I bet the textarea isn't as empty as you think it is. A string consisting of spaces is not an empty string.

Comment: im glad you pointed that out, it has spaces lol, i was scratching my head for hours trying to figure this out, but thanks it worked after i got rid of the spaces..

Comment: why have you removed your code, now this question isn't comprehensible anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You got a whitespace in your textarea after the opening tag (the underscore represents the whitespace)

```
<textarea>_
</textarea>
```

You get a whitespace, because between the open and closing tag you define the text that is in the textarea by default.

However, you should [trim](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) the textarea content to remove any whitespace characters anyway. You should consider this for the other fields, with sting input, as well.

Answer (score 0):

JS code is correct, I think the problem is the definition of Textarea. I fixed it and it works properly.

```
<textarea cols="40" rows="6" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/gwqq0x3a/ for complete example.

Answer (score -1):

Textarea elements are defined like so:

```
<textarea cols="40" rows="6" name="message" id="message"></textarea
```

No need for that input stuff, textarea is already an input, and has the name and ID declared like so, that `input type = "text"` shouldn't be there :)

Comment: True, but irrelevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: Thought the invalid stuff in the element could be breaking it before it's hit the end, therefore declaring the ID. @Quentin